# What is the dual space for the Hom vector space $\text{Hom}(V,W)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, dual-spaces

Consider, a hom-set $\text{Hom}(V,W) = \{\phi | \phi: V \to W\}$, where $V$ and $W$ both are vector spaces. This $\text{Hom}(V,W)$ can be made into a vector space over the field $K$ by defining scalar multiplication and vector addition map. Now I am trying to know what is the dual space of this $\text{Hom}(V,W)$. According to the definition of the dual space, we construct it as a set of linear maps, $f's$, that accept an element of $\text{Hom}(V,W)$ and output an element from the field $K$, $f: \text{Hom}(V,W) \to K$. Since $\text{Hom}(V,W)$ is itself a linear map from $V$ to $W$, can I define an element ($f$) of the dual space as $f: V \to W \to K$, implying the $f$ as $f: V \to K$, which is exact the dual space of $V$. Hence, this leads to an isomorphism between $\text{Hom}(V,W)^*$ and $V^*$. Actually, I am not sure about this formulation and want to know is my approach correct to define $\text{Hom}(V,W)^*$ as isomorphic to $V^*$?

Comment: Your conclusion seems quite strange, how could $Hom(V,W)^*$ not be dependent from the $W$?

Comment: Your $f: V\to W\to K$ has the braces wrong - it should be $f: (V\to W) \to K$. $f$ takes a single function an produces a scalar, while your $f:V\to W\to K$ is a 2-argument function, equivalent to $f: (V\times W)\to K$ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can identify $Hom(V,W)$ as $V^* \otimes W$ via the isomorphism
$$
\phi \otimes w \mapsto [v \mapsto \phi(v)w]
$$
where $\phi \in V^*, w \in W$ and $v \in V$. Moreover, it's not difficult to get convinced that $(V \otimes W)^* \simeq V^* \otimes W^*$ in a canonical way.

Therefore,
$$
Hom(V,W)^* \simeq (V^* \otimes W)^* \simeq V^{**} \otimes W^*.
$$
For generic vector spaces you cannot say much more, however, if $V$ is reflective (e.g. if it is finite dimensional), then $V^{**} \simeq V$ canonically and so you may find
$$
Hom(V,W)^* \simeq V \otimes W^* \simeq Hom(W,V)
$$

Comment: In view of the last part of the answer, be aware that $Hom(V,W)\cong V^*\otimes W$ holds only if at least one of the two spaces is finite dimensional. Otherwise, $V^*\otimes W$ is the subspace of linear maps of finite rank. Note also that the dual pairing between $Hom(V,W)$ and $Hom(W,V)$ can be neatly written as $(f,g)\mapsto tr(g\circ f)$.